# How to get a JSON object and put in a CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

I need to transform a JSON object to put in a CSS

I try do that with vue js, to make a map legend using v-for and generate a legend, but if you know a way than make works get a JSON object and put inside a tag in style like:

```
   {
       "color" : "red",
       "background" : "yellow"
   }

<div style="JSON RIGHT HERE"></div>
```

I really appreciate a help!!

Comment: Do you mean how can you take the properties from the object and translate them to css in the style attribute (e.g. `style="color: red; background: yellow"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Try This

```js
Vue.component('MyElement',{
    template:'<div>This is my style</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myStyle: {
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100px',
         'padding': '10px',
        'background-color': 'lime',
      },
    };
  },
  template: `<component is="MyElement" :style="myStyle"/>`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
Vue.component('some-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div :style="someStyle"></div>
      <div>This is some component</div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      someStyle: {
        width: '15em',
        height: '15em',
        'background-color': 'skyblue',
      },
    };
  },
});
```

Source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-apply-an-inline-style-inside-a-component/12829/2