# Is it possible to put a CSS template inside a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I've created the following Vue component:

```js
var loading = new Vue({
    el: "#loading_id",
    components:{
        'loading' : {
            template : `
                <div>
                    <div id="screenLoading" class="background">
                        <div class="loading">
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                            <div class="obj"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             `,
            methods: {
                startLoading: function() {
                    const load = document.getElementById("screenLoading");
                    load.classList.add('show')
                },
                stopLoading: function(){
                    const load = document.getElementById("screenLoading");
                    load.classList.remove('show')
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

loading.$children[0].startLoading()
setTimeout(() => {
    loading.$children[0].stopLoading()
}, 3500);
```

```css
.background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.background.show {
    display: flex;
}

.loading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.obj{
    width: 12px;
    height: 70px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
}

.obj:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.obj:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.obj:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.obj:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.obj:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.obj:nth-child(7){
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.obj:nth-child(8){
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes loading{
    0%{
        height: 0;
    }
    50%{
        height: 70px;
    }
    100%{
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<loading id="loading_id"></loading>
```

It works perfectly fine, its purpose is to be a loading screen for me to use when I have to make something wait on my webpage. However, instead of loading the CSS from an external CSS file with the `<style>` tag on the main HTML, I'd like to load my CSS directly from inside Vue, just like I did with the HTML on the `template` variable. Basically, it'd be something like the following:

```js
var loading = new Vue({
    el: "#loading_id",
    components:{
        'loading' : {
            template : `myHTML template`,
            cssTemplate: `myCSS template`,
            methods: {
                // my methods
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do on Vue? Can I write CSS templates inside a Vue component?

I know I also can load small pieces of CSS styles with Vue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778585/14739472), but in my case, I'd like to keep the classes and ids declaration as they are in a normal CSS file...

Comment: Yes. It’s called single file component and you will need to rely on a bundler to compile the file for you correctly. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: SFC is the recommended way to use Vue since v2. What you're doing now is a workaround that has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can include css in your vue component in the `style` tag section as below:

```css
<style scoped src="@/assets/styles/myCSSTemplate.css">
</style>
```

Also try to use proper structure when creating a vue component by having `template`, `script` and `style` sections.

For exmaple you can create Vue instane in `App.vue` and then have a component as `YourComponent.vue`

Refer to Vue documentation [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood how to implement it correctly... Is this logic only possible when I build my Vue project with WebPack? In a pure frontend Vue application like the one from my example that's not possible, is it correct?

Comment: If you don't want to refactor your code to the proper (modular) structure then you can include the css styles like this `import "@/assets/myCSSTemplatel.css"`  before creating vue install `var loading = new Vue({`